# What does it mean to subtract 'a' in order to count characters in a string using an array?

Tags: c++

How does this `hash` table work? I don't quite get it, I copied the code. Why can I minus with the char `'a'`, and somehow check if all characters occur more than once?

```
class Solution
{
public:

    //Function to check if a string is Isogram or not.
    bool isIsogram(string s)
    {
        int hash[26] = { 0 };

        //iterating over the string.
        for (int i = 0;i < s.length();i++)
        {
            //incrementing the count of characters in hash table.
            hash[s[i] - 'a']++;

            //if count of any character is greater than 1 then 
            //string is not isogram so we return false.
            if (hash[s[i] - 'a'] > 1)
                return false;
        }
        //returning true if no character occurs more than once.
        return true;
    }
};
```

Code taken from geeksforgeeks: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/check-if-a-string-is-isogram-or-not-1587115620/1/

Comment: from where did you copy the code?

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/check-if-a-string-is-isogram-or-not-1587115620/1/       After you get the solution

Comment: that assume contiguous range for `'a'-'z'` which is not guaranteed in C++ (See [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for a counter example) (but it is for `'0'-'9'`).

Comment: You could write a small program that prints `'a' - 'a'`, `'b' - 'a'`, `'c' - 'a'`, ... and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction is to map the letters `'a'` through `'z'` to `[0, 26)`. The subtraction is essentially normalizing such that `'a'` becomes `0`. This basically works by subtracting the `ord` of those chars where for example `'a'` has an ord of `97`.

With that understanding, what the loop is doing is iterating over the given string, and then incrementing the "bucket" for each of the letters `'a'`-`'z'` and returning early if any bucket has a value higher than `1`, indicating it is not unique.

Comment: There's no `ord` in C++.

Comment: @PasserBy I know, I was (poorly) trying to draw a parallel that `char` itself is a numeric type, and this behaves *like* the concept of ord (in python for example)

Comment: *"'a' has an ord of 97"* only in ASCII...

Answer (score 0):

`hash[s[i] - 'a']++;`

What this is doing is getting the ith character of the string s and the subtracting 'a' from it.  So if s is "hello" and i is 0, then `s[i]` is h.  Although you see 'h' as a letter it is also a number, 104, likewise 'a' is 97. 104 - 97 is 7.  So when the code read' it will increment the 8th element of the results array.
Using "hello" as an example string your results array would be all zeros except 7,5,14 which would be 1 and 11 which would be 2.